# How to print a string pattern?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a string with characters and a number for the rows and columns that will be in the pattern:

```
char_str1 = 'abc'
char_str1 = '31452'
num = 5
```

I would like the output to be:

```
abcab       31452
bcabc       14523
cabca       45231
abcab       52314
bcabc       23145
```

I have tried doing:

```
for i in range(num):
   for j in range(num):
       print(char_str1, end='')
   print()
output:
abcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabcabc
abcabcabcabcabc
```

Comment: Python [modulo](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/) can help you turn 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 into 0,1,2,0,1,2,0 (using modulo 3, for example).

Comment: both variables have the same name `char_str1 = 'abc'` overwrites `char_str1 = '31452'`

Comment: I dont think anyone can understand your rules for this thing given the current text of the question ... please try to explain again what you expect and why (what rules is it following)

Answer (score 1):

If you replicate the strings at least `num` times, simple slicing works.  The original strings need to be at least length 1 of course:

```py
char_str1 = 'abc'
char_str2 = '31452'   # You had a typo here st1 instead of str2
num = 5

a = char_str1 * num
b = char_str2 * num

for i in range(num):
   print(a[i:i+num], b[i:i+num])
```

Output:

```
abcab 31452
bcabc 14523
cabca 45231
abcab 52314
bcabc 23145
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code in java for your pattern!!

> JAVA

```java
public class Main {
  public static void printPattern(String s, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j < n + i; j++) {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(j % s.length()));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printPattern("abc", 5);
    printPattern("31452", 5);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Python

```py
def printPattern(s, n):
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n + i):
      print(s[j % len(s)], end='')
    print()
    
printPattern("abc", 5);
printPattern("31452", 5);
```

Comment: Question is tagged `python`.

Comment: yes, i can see that as well, but can definitely get the idea what to do in python!!

Comment: if you are not getting what to do in python, let me know I will edit my JAVA code to python language...waiting for your response Thank you in advance

Comment: would you be able to edit your code to python? thanks

Comment: @minkp90 yes, sure please have a look I have added code in python as well !!